# Array push as the first index PHP

Tags: php, arrays, push

I have an array that doesn't use the 0 index. The array starts from 1,2,3. So I would like to add to the array. I tried do `array_push($array, "Choose City")`, but this ends up at the end of the array, with array index 4 in this case.

How can I set it to be the array index 0?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

```
array_unshift($array, "Choose City")
```

or you can do it manually

Comment: @DaveRandom the question is "How can i set it to be the array index 0?" :)

Comment: @Oyeme While `$array[0] = ` is a valid answer, it only works once. Using `array_unshift()` has exactly the same effect on the first call, and works as many times as you want. Sometimes the literal answer is not the best answer...

Comment: @DaveRandom it's true,"Question is not exact"

Comment: function array_unshift_assoc(&$arr, $key, $val) 
     { 
         $arr = array_reverse($arr, true); 
         $arr[$key] = $val; 
         return = array_reverse($arr, true); 
     }

Comment: @mvladk Could you explain why we should use this solution, please? Is there a situation that this solution will work better than `array_unshift`?

Comment: @RohamRafii "if you need to prepend something to the array without the keys being reindexed and/or need to prepend a key value pair".
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php#106570

Answer (score 14):

I think you are looking for [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) - this adds an element to the beginning of the array, rather than the end, without overwriting any existing elements.

However, the array will now be indexed starting at `0`...

Answer (score 9):

If you know that Index 0 is not used you can simply assign it:

```
$array[0] = "Choose City";
```

Comment: @Matteo The OP said so. This is the simplest answer to add a new element with index 0 to the start of an array (that does not already have one with that index). Other answers make no assumptions about the state of the array and are therefore more robust.

Comment: I understand. I'll give you a +1 because actually this is the answer to the specific question. Even if the solution is not general

Comment: Omg, this is actually a valid answer and maybe the best! Note: the question is ambiguous. What does it mean "doesn't use the 0 index"? Is it an initial state (can be changed) or an invariant (must be preserved)? In the first case, this is the best answer, in the second case, none of the answers is correct. +1