# Custom ordering array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here's my array

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 4ff6e96bb0b4599016000006
        )

    [alias] => me
    [create] => 1341581675
    [name] => It's Me!
)
```

I set `[id] => 4ff6e96bb0b4599016000006` and unset `[_id]`

Now

```
Array
(
    [alias] => me
    [create] => 1341581675
    [name] => It's Me!
    [id] => 4ff6e96bb0b4599016000006 
)
```

What's the best way to order `[id]` on top and order `[create]` after `[name]`

Thanks

Comment: Why does it matter the order for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array push as the first index PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340451/array-push-as-the-first-index-php)

Comment: That is a valid case when dealing with numbered indexes, not named ones.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu designing array API key :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting `$yourArray['id'] = '4ff6e9...0006'`, you could (ab)use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to add it:

```
$yourArray = array_merge(array('id'=>'4ff6e9...006'), $yourArray);
```

This should basically append your original array to the small array above which contains only the key 'id'.